# Is it possible to group segments in Retrieve PNR response?

Tags: sabre

I'm currently retrieving a PNR information using the Retrieve PNR API. For display, i need to group the flights by legs. However, the flight returned in the view i'm using (`DefaultWithPq`) are simply returned as a single sequence of segments :

```
<stl18:Segments>
  <stl18:Segment sequence="1" id="8">
  ...
  <stl18:Segment sequence="2" id="9">
  ...
  <stl18:Segment sequence="3" id="10">
  ...
  <stl18:Segment sequence="4" id="11">
  ...
</stl18:Segments>
```

How is it possible from those sequence (without calculating with departure times destinations etc.) to know which ones are in the departure leg and which ones are in the return leg ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this would be have to be done by your application's logic, as the service does not return that information. You can use dates and marriage indicators but there is no element to show which one is the inbound or outbound flight. Usually customers obtain this with shopping services like BFM.